# Wrong 9 patch init size while displays

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

Created nine patch image via Android Studio from png file. Set patch image as background on ImageView, but ImageView shows with greater size as expected. Studio shows that image has size 117*95, but on display imageView shows with size near 334*266.
Please, help how to fix it. Png and screens attached.

```html
<ImageView android:background="@drawable/new_sent_bubble_edit1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

[nine patch view in studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O83R.png)

[image: view on xxhpi screen]

Comment: How did you measure the size on android screen and how in android studio?

Comment: Adroid Studio shows resolution and image size info when just open image. Also took screenshot from phone via Android Studio and opened it in any editor on PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution. Just need to put 9 patch file to some density drawable folder. When put picture to xxhdpi-drawable folder and image has been drawn as expected.